# Policy related cakePHP bake command does't work(in my case)

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-bake, cakephp-4.x

I am working on cakePHP (version 4.0.5) and when I tried to run

> bin/cake bake policy --type entity Name

command, It'll gives an error .

> Error: Unknown option `type`.

Can anyone encounter such problem and have any solution,kindly share...

Comment: try `bin/cake policy --type entity Name` because https://github.com/cakephp/authorization/tree/master/src/Command

Comment: @Salines It's a bake command, it is being [**registered as `bake policy`**](https://github.com/cakephp/authorization/blob/2.0.3/src/Plugin.php#L37).

Comment: @ndm OK, I don't use it, only have quick look at source code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just ran into this message when I missed loading the Authorization plugin.  Check you have loaded the plugin by adding the following statement to the bootstrap() method in src/Application.php:

```
$this->addPlugin('Authorization');
```

reference: https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/tutorials-and-examples/cms/authorization.html